# Enabling HA namenodes on a secure cluster in Cloudera Manager fails

Tags: hdfs, cloudera, high-availability

I am running a CDH4.1.2 secure cluster and it works fine with the single namenode+secondarynamenode configuration, but when I try to enable High Availability (quorum based) from the Cloudera Manager interface it dies at step 10 of 16, "Starting the NameNode that will be transitioned to active mode namenode ([my namenode's hostname])".

Digging into the role log file gives the following fatal error:

```
Exception in namenode joinjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: [my namenode's fqhn]:[my namenode's fqhn]:0 at
org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:206) at
org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:158) at
org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:147) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeHttpServer.start(NameNodeHttpServer.java:143) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:547) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startCommonServices(NameNode.java:480) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:443) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:608) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:589) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1140) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1204)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two problems:

1. The NameNode's IP address is resolving to "my namenode's fqhn" instead of a regular hostname. Check your /etc/hosts file to fix this.
2. You need to configure dfs.https.port. With Cloudera Manager free edition, you must have had to add the appropriate configs to the safety valves to enable security. As part of that, you need to configure the dfs.https.port.

Given that this code path is traversed even in the non-HA mode, I'm surprised that you were able to get your secure NameNode to start up correctly before enabling HA. In case you haven't already, I recommend that you first enable security, test that all HDFS roles start up correctly and then enable HA.